# How to define implicit function with a type parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am reading [Hands-on Scala Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9811456933) and I am stuck on recursive typeclass inference.

The section explains how to write a parser from multiple data types. It gives the example below

```
trait StrParser[T]{ def parse(s: String): T }
object StrParser{
  implicit object ParseInt extends StrParser[Int]{
    def parse(s: String) = s.toInt
  }
  implicit object ParseBoolean extends StrParser[Boolean]{
    def parse(s: String) = s.toBoolean
  }
  implicit object ParseDouble extends StrParser[Double]{
    def parse(s: String) = s.toDouble
  }
}
```

The above code works well. After that, it moves on to recursive typeclass inference. It shows an implication function below.

```
implicit def ParseSeq[Int](implicit p: StrParser[Int]) = new StrParser[Seq[Int]]{
  def parse(s: String) = s.split(',').toSeq.map(p.parse)
}
```

However, I face an error after I ran this code. I tried it on Ammonite, Scala, and compile it but everything does not work.

```
result type of implicit definition needs to be given explicit
```

I look up the error on google and only found two non-related results. How can I fix this issue? What am I missing?

Comment: First, you don't want to name your generic `Int`, that would be confusing, use a single letter like `A` or `T` - Second, the error is pretty clear, you have to be explicit with the return type of your `implicit def` try: `implicit def ParseSeq[T](implicit ev: StrParser[T]): StrParser[Seq[T]] =`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez where can I read more about explicit return type? I am new to Scala

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean? BTW, if you are new to the language maybe you would want to join the [**Discord** server](https://discord.gg/9nPaEYgp) which would be better for this kind of questions.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will join it. For my question, I want to understand why I need to explicitly specify the result type in Scala 3. It seems like a breaking change and I want to know the reason behind it.

Comment: To be honest no idea, the technically correct answer is because the compiler says so, period. Anyways, you always want to be explicit with return types, which helps with documentation and catching bugs.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is written for Scala 2, which handles this code [without error](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zQxCaxgvSoGRrw4HNNoDDA):

```scala
trait StrParser[T]{ def parse(s: String): T }
object StrParser{
  implicit object ParseInt extends StrParser[Int]{
    def parse(s: String) = s.toInt
  }
  implicit object ParseBoolean extends StrParser[Boolean]{
    def parse(s: String) = s.toBoolean
  }
  implicit object ParseDouble extends StrParser[Double]{
    def parse(s: String) = s.toDouble
  }
}

implicit def ParseSeq[T](implicit p: StrParser[T]) = new StrParser[Seq[T]]{
  def parse(s: String) = s.split(',').toSeq.map(p.parse)
}

def parseFromString[T](s: String)(implicit parser: StrParser[T]) = {
  parser.parse(s)
}

parseFromString[Seq[Int]]("1,1")
```

It seems that [you are using Scala 3](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/a5uWexn8Th6sCkJMnnTlnA), for it you will need [to change your `ParseSeq` definition to](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YWxxyMioSXmpSq6AZ8oW6A):

```scala
implicit def ParseSeq[T](implicit p: StrParser[T]): StrParser[Seq[T]] = new StrParser[Seq[T]]{
  def parse(s: String) = s.split(',').toSeq.map(p.parse)
}
```

Also note that the book defines `ParseSeq` as a [generic method](https://github.com/handsonscala/handsonscala/blob/v1/snippets/5.48.scala) with parameter name `T`, which is better generic parameter name than one mathcing existing type (i.e. `Int`):

```scala
implicit def ParseSeq[T](implicit p: StrParser[T]) = new StrParser[Seq[T]]{
  def parse(s: String) = s.split(',').toSeq.map(p.parse)
}
```

Comment: If the error only happens on **Scala 3** wouldn't it better to use `given / using`?

Comment: What is this called in Scala 3? Where can I read more about this?

Comment: @CodeProject it is a [new version](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/new-in-scala3.html) of language.